# Remove Renderer from a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, render

I have a JTable with a Renderer written by myself. When I set the JTable disabled, I want it to be painted in gray, and with the current Renderer that's not possible. That's why I want to  remove the renderer when I set the JTable disabled, and then when enabled set it again.

Is that possible, or may I take a different solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a new DefaultTableRenderer(). It should be possible too in your Renderer. Alternatively you could extend DefaultTableRenderer.

Comment: Of course I can. I should have thought of that myself. Sorry, it is Monday... :)

Comment: please be precise: the class name is "DefaultTableCellRenderer". Anyway, that wouldn't help - the default implementation doesn't respect table's enabled state

Answer (score 3):

Before setting your custom renderer, get the default renderer from the JTable. Store it in a reference for later use. Now set your custom renderer to JTable.

Before disabling the table, set the default one and when you enable it set the custom one.

I hope this should work for you.

Comment: As already mentioned in my comment to the other incorrect (the part related to DefaultTableCellRenderer), the default implementation does not respect table's enabled state

Answer (score 2):

use JXTable (from the [SwingX project](http://swingx.java.net)) - its renderers respect the table enablement automatically

**Edit**

on reading again:

> I have a JTable with a Renderer written by myself. When I set the
>   JTable disabled, I want it to be painted in gray, and with the current
>   Renderer that's not possible

why isn't that possible? In your custom renderer simply query the table enablement and configure its state accordingly

```
 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(...) {
     ...
     myRenderingComponent.setEnabled(table.isEnabled());
     return myRenderingComponent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the table is enabled when the renderer component is returned.  You can then set a state variable in the renderer which will render the cell differently when it is disabled than when it is enabled.  This approach also makes it possible to allow for other states - I have a renderer that allows for different "profiles" depending on values in a specific column.